# Best way to group a query result by a column in SQL Server or using C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a search form in C# and I have two tables which users can search in them, one of them is property table and another one is users. As you know each user can have more than one property. So if I want to find users that have a property with color=red and price X when I run query it gives me many users and some of them is duplicated I mean the the phone number of users are same. So as the result of a query that user does I have a result such as this

```
User.name|user.phone|product.color|product.price|product.id
-----------------------------------------------------------
a        |9828393999|red          |XX           |yt3
a        |9828393999|red          |XX           |y23
b        |9828393994|red          |XX           |3t3
b        |9828393994|red          |XX           |4t3
```

This is a result of query that user performs..How I can get only phone numbers and name? I want something like this

```
User.name|user.phone|product.color|product.price|product.id
-----------------------------------------------------------
a        |9828393999|red          |XX           |y23
b        |9828393994|red          |XX           |4t3
```

Here is a sample query that I get from user

```
select 
   u.Name, u.Family, u.OBJECTID, u.phone,
   p.number, p.Energy, p.Area, p.contex, p.title 
from 
   [dbo].[user] as u, [dbo].[PROPERTY] as p 
where 
   u.OBJECTID = p.owner_ID and [contex] = 0 and [title] = 2
```

No matters `product.id`, I just want the phone numbers.. So what is best method to do it?
Can I perform such thing in SQL Server? Or I must use codes?

One way that I can do is loop among data and get phone numbers. But I think it is some how not a good method..Can you help me find a good solution for this?

Thank you very much

Comment: You can do it in SQL.   Google for some tutorials on "SQL GROUP BY"

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have tried looping in results and getting the phone numbers it works but I think for a table for 30000 records it is not good to do that

Comment: @TabAlleman I have tried to use this sql statement but I need sth like count,Max or min,Right?Which column do I should use for it?I totally confused how to use groupby by a result like what I mentioned in question

Comment: What's your input to the table, can u clearly confirm the same? and wht is the table structure of other table?

Comment: @knkarthick24 I added a sample query that shows the structure of tables,what I have added in qustion is the resut of a query and I want to qroup the result

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do for this type of thing...
Step 1) Create a model of your class...

```
public class MyModel {
      public string UserName {get;set;}
      public string UserPhone {get;set;}
      public string ProductColor {get;set;}
      public string ProductPrice {get;set;}
      public string ProductID {get;set;}

}
```

Then I use Enitity Framework to project the results into that model like this.

```
using(var db = new MyEntities(){ 
  string Query = "Select XYZ from Tablea,TableB where something=@parm";      
  SqlParameter[] parms = {new SqlParameter{name = "parm" value="somevalue");       
  var stuff = db.Database.SQLQuery<MyModel>(query, parms.ToArray());
  return stuff.ToList();
}
```

Stuff will contain IEnumerable

Now you can use LINQ to filter what ever you want.

```
var grp = stuff.GroupBy(p=>p.UserPhone);
var justPhoneNumbers = stuff.Where(p=>p.ProductColor=="Red").Select(p=>p.UserPhone).ToList();
var filtered = stuff.Where(p=>p.ProductColor=="Red").ToList();
var filtered2 = stuff.Where(p=>p.ProductColor=="Red");
 filtered2= filtered2.Where(p=>p.UserName == "Jones");
var finallist = filtered2.ToList();
```

Then just bind the results to the view and you're all set.

Comment: Does in step 3 I can group data by phone?I dont think so..I mean for example the 'justPhoneNumbers' gives me series of duplicated numbers..right?I'll run the code now and see what heppens